# Show that $\mathbb{Z}/a \otimes \mathbb{Z}/ab$ is not zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

This question is motivated by the fact that, if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ then $\mathbb{Z}/a \otimes \mathbb{Z}/b$ is zero tensor product.

> I would like to show that $\mathbb{Z}/a \otimes \mathbb{Z}/ab$ is not zero.

My thought is that try to use contradiction. Suppose $M= \mathbb{Z}/a \otimes \mathbb{Z}/ab$ is zero tensor product, then let $P$ be some $\mathbb{Z}$-module with homomorphism $f$, $P$ will have to be zero. This is due to the universal property of tensor product. More specifically, for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}/a \times \mathbb{Z}/ab$,

$$f(a,b)=\tilde{f}\circ \phi(a,b) = \tilde{f}(0)=0.$$

where $\phi$ is the bilinear map comes with $M$.

So it suffices to find such a bilinear map and a module that, definitely is non zero. But I am having trouble finding that.

Comment: To add onto Henning's answer: multiplication is the most bilinear thing there is. So you want to find a $P$ where it is possible to multiply elements of $\mathbb Z/a$ and $\mathbb Z/(ab)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to see with $\mathbf Z$: for *any* (commutative) ring $R$, and ideals $I,J\subseteq R$, one has
$$R/I\otimes_R R/J\simeq R/(I+J).\tag{1}$$
Furthermore, if $J\subseteq I$, $I+J=I$, so that
$$R/I\otimes_R R/J\simeq R/I.$$

*A proof of* $(1)$:

For any $R$-module $M$, one has $\;R/I\otimes_RM\simeq M/IM$. In particular
$$R/I\otimes_R R/J\simeq \simeq (R/J)/(I\cdot R/J)=(R/J)/\bigl((I+J)/J\bigr)\simeq R/(I+J)$$
by the *Third isomorphism theorem*.

Comment: This looks like a really useful result. Where can I find proof for that?

Comment: @Misakov: I've added a short proof.

Comment: @Bernard Snap! When I learned about third isomorphism theorem in my first algebra course I never understood why it would be useful haha.

Answer (score 2):

How about $P=\mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z$ and $f(x,y)=xy$?

(More explicitly: $f(x,y)=x\psi(y)$ where $\psi$ is the natural homomorphism $\mathbb Z/ab\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: For $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ do you know what $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to?